# Reshaping data from an from-to format into country-year in R

Tags: r, formatting, time-series, reshape

I have a data set containing information about political leaders in the following format:

```
leader    country    begin    end
clinton   USA        1994     2001
bush      USA        2002     2009
...       ...        ...      ...
```

In order to merge it with other data, however, I would like to reshape it into the commonly used country-year format, like the following:

```
country    year    leader
USA        1994    clinton
USA        1995    clinton
```

My current approach (creating an empty data frame and using a nested for-loop) takes a very long time  and tbh seems very stupid. As the dataset is rather large I am looking for a smarter and more efficient way to do this.

PS: Dont worry about the weird years, the leaders are assigned to years which they already started as the leader. which is why Bush starts only in 2002 not 2001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
df <- structure(list(leader = structure(2:1, .Label = c("bush", "clinton"
), class = "factor"), country = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "USA", class = "factor"), 
    begin = c(1994L, 2002L), end = c(2001L, 2009L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df %>% 
group_by(leader,country) %>% 
expand(year=begin:end) %>%
arrange(year)
```

You get for every country+leader, all the years between begin and end

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   leader, country [2]
   leader  country  year
   <fct>   <fct>   <int>
 1 clinton USA      1994
 2 clinton USA      1995
 3 clinton USA      1996
 4 clinton USA      1997
 5 clinton USA      1998
 6 clinton USA      1999
 7 clinton USA      2000
 8 clinton USA      2001
 9 bush    USA      2002
10 bush    USA      2003
11 bush    USA      2004
12 bush    USA      2005
13 bush    USA      2006
14 bush    USA      2007
15 bush    USA      2008
16 bush    USA      2009
```